# Plotting pre-gridded data in contour or contourf - Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

This, I think, should be very simple, but I can't seem to find documentation or an example that works for what I want to do. I'd like to plot a matplotlib contourf plot which represents the values of an attribute at each point on a grid. The data is already uniformly spaced (eg, at 1m intervals)
The data is held in a numpy array:

```
data = numpy.array([[x1,y1,z1],
                       [x2,y2,y3],
                       [x3.........etc
```

where the xn and yn values are coordinates, and the zn represents the value i want to visualise. There is a lot of data (up to 1million points)

All the examples I can find use griddata, and so this is what I have tried to use, but it seems like an unnecessary overhead to me, as my data has already been gridded well before this stage. Anyway - I tried:

```
maxX = max(data[:,0])
minX = min(data[:,0])
maxY = max(data[:,1])
minY = min(data[:,1])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

xi = np.linspace(minX, maxX, maxX-minX+1)
yi = np.linspace(minY, maxY, maxY-minY+1)

zi = griddata(data[:,0],data[:,1], data[:,2], xi, yi, interp ='linear')

cont = ax.contourf(xi,yi,zi,15,cmap=plt.cm.jet)

plt.show()
```

but I get a runtime error, "Triangulation is invalid"

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tri\trifinder.py", line 81, in _initialize
self._cpp_trifinder.initialize()
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Can I do this without gridding and interpolating as the data is already uniformly distributed?

Many thanks

Comment: When you say the data is already uniformly spaced, does it also mean that the data is in order? Then you could just use `numpy.reshape`. If you could provide some test data, that would also make it easier to see whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using griddata in scipy rather than griddata in matplotlib,
i.e. instead of:
`from matplotlib.mlab import griddata` 
use: 
`from scipy.interpolate import griddata`)
This worked for me.